# Invalid result returned from the software lookup service

Tags: ios, xcode, organizer

I tried to submit an iOS app via XCode organizer, but it failed right after authentication and organizer said "Invalid result returned from the software lookup service".

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Check that your app status is "Waiting for Upload" in iTunes Connect.
You can change the status to press "Ready to Upload Binary" blue button.

Comment: Thanks! I confused between 'ready to upload' and 'waiting for upload'.

Answer (score 3):

Check that your app is "Ready to upload" in iTunes Connect (I had this error when I rejected a binary and forgot to reset it to "Ready to Upload")