# Application Loader is currently unavailable

Tags: iphone, xcode, itunes, organizer

Does anyone know what this error message means: *"Invalid result returned from the software lookup service"* , I am getting this for the past 2 days both on **application loader** and **xcode organizer** when I try to upload my binary.

Comment: This worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161568/invalid-result-returned-from-the-software-lookup-service

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it seems I forgot to change the state to ready for upload, thanks gebirgsbaerbel.